# How to install 3rd party plugins in Asp.net zero?

Tags: c#, npm, asp.net-core, angular5, aspnetboilerplate

I am creating a Forum application on Asp.net zero 2.1 . Now I want to install a ckeditor in npm to write post like Stack overflow. I am able to install it, But then when I run application, it gives me 100 errors like "Cannot find module '@abp/abpHttpInterceptor'", "Error in multi" etc.

Also it doesn't uninstall properly, it delete packages with it.

I also tried deleting node modules and then re-install, but it misses out on some modules.

Any help appreciated. Do the asp.net boilerplate face this issue ?

Comment: If you create a new web project and do not install this npm package, does the project compile and run OK?

Comment: yes I kept a backup of this project, without this ckeditor npm install, project runs fine.

Comment: Try [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/).

Comment: @aaron yes it did work, thanks man
have you implemented an infinite scroll for paging with yarn ?
As npm is not working with Asp.net zero.

Comment: Yarn and npm are just package managers.

Comment: @aaron , I know that, but this isn't working for asp.net zero 5.2
I can do that with javascript but would be great if I can get an angular 2+ plugin  compliant with yarn